# why is the curl of a function (which looks like a vortex) zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition, curl

Can anyone explain why the curl of this function zero ? Clearly it's rotating then how is it irrotational ? Someone on SE said

> Not to mistake Curl for rotation, they aren't exactly similar.

Is this true ?

$\vec{V}(x,y,z)=[\frac{−y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},0]$

[image: 3D Vector Field Plot Fig]

Image Source: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector+field+of+V(x,y,z)%3D%5B%E2%88%92y%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2),x%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2),0%5D)

Edit : As pointed by [Rahul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/856/rahul) the topic of irrotational vortices have been already discussed over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428839/irrotational-vortices), that somehow clears my intuitive understanding of curl: rotating the particles about their axes and not just revolving around center (which [Travis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/155629/travis) has already pointed out in his answer) of the vortex but this still doesn't clear up my doubt about why the intuitive understanding doesn't match the calculations.

If the curl is present at the center (z-axis), why doesn't it show up in the result (which is zero)?

Comment: To add to what Travis said, intuitively, it should have curl zero everywhere except on the z-axis (that’s where the “curl” is happening). The problem is that the function (and the curl) aren’t defined there.

Comment: @ChandlerWatson Is it because the z component is zero ?

Comment: The animation in [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/428870/856) is illuminating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Irrotational Vortices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428839/irrotational-vortices)

Comment: @Rahul I understand curl a little better now after seeing "Irrotational Vortex" but in the post you mentioned, a user said and I quote " The curl in the center is not defined, since the flow is not continuous at this point, although a physicist would say that the curl at the center point is infinite." What is meant by "not continuous" or even "infinite" ? How an undefined curl is equal to zero curl?

Comment: It's not. The curl of the vector field is zero everywhere *except at the center*.

Comment: @Rahul no I mean w.r.t. to the given function in this question, the curl is zero. Why doesn't that centre curl show up in the calculation ?

Comment: @paulplusx it’s because the x and y components are zero on the z axis. In general, a function isn’t (partially) differentiable where it doesn’t exist, because the difference quotient uses the value of the function at that point. We need the partial derivatives to exist to compute the curl. Regarding the rotation thing also, check [this](https://mathinsight.org/curl_subtleties) out :)

Comment: @ChandlerWatson Thanks, I think I understand it better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the $\bf V$ is "rotating" in that sense that, informally, if you place a particle in $\Bbb R^3 - \{\textrm{$z$-axis}\}$ and let it move with velocity the value of $\bf V$ wherever it is, after time $t$ it will have rotated anticlockwise $t$ radians about the $z$-axis.

However, $\operatorname{curl}$ doesn't measure this sort of rotation---rather, it measures *the infinitesimal rotation of the vector field* about each point, and for the particular vector field $\bf V$ this rotation is zero about every point.

Comment: Isn't the vector field rotating ? (It looks like that). How can you intuitively explain a non rotating (formally : irrotational) vector graphically w.r.t the given function?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, it is rotating in the sense I specified in the first sentence. Put very informally, the vector field is rotating about the $z$-axis, but it's not rotating around any other point.

Comment: So if the vector is rotating around z (which fits the intuition) why don't we have a curl z-component ? Like everyone else said "the function is not defined there " . Is it because of 0 z component in the function?

Comment: The curl measures the infinitesimal rotation of a vector field around a point (in the domain). Yes, $\bf V$ is not defined where $x = y = 0$ because the coefficients aren't defined there.

Comment: Aaah. I am an idiot not to see the undefined region (origin) of the function. I can now see why the curl is zero :The computation generates the value of the curl only for defined regions but in this peculiar case the curl is present in the undefined region (z-axis) which is why it's not being picked up by the formula. Is this understanding correct ? @Travis

Comment: Yes, basically---the curl simply isn't defined on the $z$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Curl measures the *local* rotation about a point - or better, it measures the extent to which the field *locally fails to be conservative*: that is, if we consider this a field of force, like a gravitational or electric field, and I put a charged particle, or particle that is otherwise responsive to this force, in it and then take it around a tiny loop (ideally: infinitely small), do I get any net work and, if so, how much? If the curl vanishes everywhere on a simply-connected domain, the field is conservative on that domain.

It is thus a complicated kind of differential operator - an operator that reveals a local property of a function: a property that holds within an ideally small ("infinitesimal") area around a point. The simplest one is the derivative in one variable, which reveals how a function stretches/squeezes about that point The existence of a differential operator at a point implies a certain regularity, while its non-existence implies a certain pathology in that area. Thus it should not be surprising that $\mathbb{curl}\ \mathbf{F}$ can be written as $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$.

In the case of the origin point, the curl is undefined and thus it tells you nothing about whether or not any work can be done in moving thereabout. The point is pathological as the function is not defined there and moreover the local neighborhood looks dramatically different. In this case, it turns out you can't do any work, but there are other cases where you can (even while the curl is zero elsewhere, meaning that a loop around them that is small enough to exclude the origin point will not achieve any work). The domain of this field is not simply connected as the origin is missing.

Comment: So can we say that the curl is present about z axis but as the z component of the function is zero, the function is not defined there ?